# Output mysql laravel collection corrupt

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to have a collection from a laravel model. However the output is corrupt because of the special character é

If I do a dd($collection) it shows up like this:

"name" => b"Privéles 30 min. per week"

So somehow this weird "b" shows up next to the =>

I tried the usual encodings but I can't get rid of it. (utf-8 or uft8mb4)

Database settings in laravel:

```
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
```

I use Laravel 5.7

Also, locally this works just fine and this "b" does not appear.

Local php is 7.2.12
Server php is 7.2.14

Local mysql = 5.7.22
Server mysql = 5.6.33

Comment: If the character has already been incorrectly stored in the database then whatever you do to the encoding afterwards will not fix it. You should focus on figuring out why it ended up stored badly in the database (if that's indeed the case).

Comment: It it stored correctly in de database. Just reading from it gave the error as described.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was using a dynamic connection, so I also had to add this:
Config::set('database.connections.dynamic.charset','utf8');
So it's solved.